# How do I remove a tag from a task with a @ManyToMany relationship using Spring Boot JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I'm currently working on a task/project/tags web application in Java with extensive use of Spring Boot JPA (I'm relatively new to this framework so bear with me). I've declared a @ManyToMany relationship between the Task and Tag entity (defined below).

Task Entity:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@Entity()
@Table(name = "tasks_dim")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String status;

    private String priority;

    @Column(name = "task_id_number", unique = true)
    private String taskIdNumber;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinTable(name = "task_tags_dim",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "due_date")
    private Date dueDate;

    public Task(String name, String status, String priority, User user) {
        setName(name);
        setDescription(description);
        setStatus(status);
        setPriority(priority);
        setTaskIdNumber(new TaskIdNumberBuilder().buildTaskIdNumber());
        setUser(user);
        setDueDate(dueDate);
        Timestamp currentTime = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
        setCreatedOn(currentTime);
        setLastUpdatedOn(currentTime);
    }
```

Tag Entity:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@Entity()
@Table(name = "tags_dim")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Task> tasks = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Tag(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }
```

However, I'm having issues with my TagService class as I'm unable to use getTags() within in my removeTag method. It returns an empty set, so there is nothing to remove even though I am adding a tag within my create() and addTag() method. If I make use of setTags() in create(), I still wouldn't be able to get any data from getTags() in the other methods.
Note:

- create() creates a new Tag object, add a link between the
  newly-created tag object and its respective task, and save it into
  the database
- addTag() adds a link between an existing tag and a given
- task removeTag() remove the link between an exising tag and given
- task delete() deletes the tag all together (all links between the tag
  and any task should be deleted)

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TagService {
    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    public Tag create(User user, Tag tag, Long task_id) {
        try {
            Optional<Task> optionalTask = taskRepository.findById(task_id);
            if (optionalTask.isPresent()) {
                Tag tagDetails = new Tag(tag.getName());
                Tag savedTag = tagRepository.save(tagDetails);
                Task currentTask = optionalTask.get();

                currentTask.getTags().add(savedTag);
                taskRepository.save(currentTask);
                return savedTag;
            }
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tag '" + tag.getName() + "' already exists.");
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Task not found for the given task_id: " + task_id);
    }

    public Tag addTag(Tag tag, Long task_id) {
        Optional<Task> optionalTask = taskRepository.findById(task_id);
        if(optionalTask.isPresent()) {
            Task task = optionalTask.get();
            try {
                task.getTags().add(tag);
                taskRepository.save(task);
                return tag;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tag '" + tag.getName() + "' is a duplicate entry.");
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Task not found for the given task_id: " + task_id);
    }


    public Set<Tag> getByTask(Long task_id) {
        Optional<Task> optionalTask = taskRepository.findById(task_id);
        if(optionalTask.isPresent()) {
            Set<Tag> myTags = optionalTask.get().getTags();
            for(Tag tag: myTags) {
                System.out.println(tag.getName());
            }
            return tagRepository.findByTasks(optionalTask.get());
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Task not found for the given task_id: " + task_id);
    }

    public Set<Tag> removeTag(Tag tag, Long task_id) {
        Optional<Task> optionalTask = taskRepository.findById(task_id);
        try {
            if(optionalTask.isPresent()) {

                Task currentTask = optionalTask.get();
                System.out.println(currentTask.getTags());
                return currentTask.getTags();
            }
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tag not found for the given task_id: " + task_id);
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Request to remove tag from given task id '" + task_id + "' could not be processed");
    }

    public void delete(Tag tag) {
        tagRepository.deleteById(tag);
    }
}
```

I've tried to make use of [Hibernate.initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318340/how-hibernate-initialize-works) but no luck. Is 'FetchType.LAZY' the ideal type for this use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Optional Solution 1 : Use @Getter and @Setter instead of @Data in the Task class.

Optional Solution 2 : `@ToString` and `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotations within `@Data` annotation may cause problems. If you want to use `@Data`, you should override the toString(), equals() and hashCode() methods.

Optional solution 3 : Just add `@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")` to Task class.

Comment: All options are failing for me unfortunately. Seems to be throwing a StackOverflow exception if I try to override the equals() method and when I add EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id") / Getter / Setter

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ Idea, clearing the cache from the link below may help. Then, if you are using Maven, you can run the command below and try again.


[Invalidate caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html). 

`mvn clean install -U`

Comment: Firstly, can you add `@Getter` and `@Setter` to both Task class and Tag class? please remove `@Data`